# angular 5 *ngFor two array (merge objects of two arrays to make single array of objects)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular5

I am getting array from two get method in angular 5. What i want is to combine those two arrays (JSON) into one array and print it in a single for loop

my two arrays:-

```
servers3 =[
{
  sub:'sub',
  subDesc:'subDesc'
}];

public tableData:any;
```

i am using concat two combine two arrays like follows

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>fileName</th>
    <th>icon</th>
    <th>fullPath</th>
    <th>sub</th>
    <th>subDesc</th>
    <th>image</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of tableData.concat(servers3)">
    <td>{{item?.fileName}}</td>
    <td>{{item?.icon}} </td>
    <td>{{item?.fullPath}}</td>
    <td>{{item?.sub}}</td>
    <td>{{item?.subDesc}}</td>
    <td><img src="{{item?.fullPath}}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="adawdawd"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And i am getting output as follows:-

[image]

as you can see its not showing in one line 
each array completes individually

please give me solution if any one know the answer
thank you in advance

Comment: your second array item only has `sub` and `subDesc` properties, so they're showing up in those template locations. Also, you'll want to handle the structure in the array and reference it from the loop as one variable, not do the concatenation in the template.

Comment: what i want is two print those two array item in same row because they both have equal size or say index of data

Comment: ...then you'll need to write some code to flatten out those items in the array instead of just concatenating them in the template.

Comment: can you please tell me the method i cant seems to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following keeping in mind that length of both the arrays should be same otherwise it will generate error.

```
this.tableData.map((item, index) => {
     return Object.assign(item, servers3[index]));
});
```

**HTML**

```
...
<tr *ngFor="let item of tableData">
...
```

Comment: thanks this worked , map that  function right after i set the value of tableData.

Comment: happy to hear that.